# Hot reload cannot work in JS/TS projects when JS/TS modules imported

Tags: javascript, typescript, stackblitz

I've created a simple JS or TS project and I wrote some common functions. Hot reload on Edit worked fine till I moved these common functions into a separated module file.

BEFORE
index.ts:

```
function devPrint(msg: string, color?: string, nl?: boolean) {
  _devPrint({msg:msg, color:color, nl:true})
}

...

devPrint('this: ' + this + ', param1: ' + param1);
```

AFTER: 
index.ts:

```
import {devPrint, devPrintNoNL, devPrintFlush} from './devPrinter';

...

devPrint('this: ' + this + ', param1: ' + param1);
```

devPrinter.ts:

```
export function devPrint(msg: string, color?: string, nl?: boolean) {
  _devPrint({msg:msg, color:color, nl:true})
}

....
```

Hot reload itself works (JS console refreshed), but new content cannot be rendered, there is only an empty browser panel.

If I change 'Hot reload' to 'Page reload' in Settings everything works fine. It's my workaround now but I'd like to know what can be the problem with Hot reload.

[You can find original project here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ftoth-typescript-function)